# Notepad ++ Way to indent to a specific column with shortcut

Tags: notepad++, indentation

Does anyone know of a way in Notepad++ to write a shortcut/automation to indent text to a specific column.

For example:

```
SELECT 
  name  NameColumn
, value  ValueColumn
FROM 
  table
```

What I would like to do is be able to hit a key combination (on each line as I go) that would tab to a specific location.  My aliases should always be at column X in the page

```
SELECT 
  name                             NameColumn
, value                            ValueColumn
FROM 
  table
```

Anyone have any ideas.

Thanks
Matt

Answer (score 0):

Using [AutoHotKey](http://ahkscript.org) you can create keyboard shortcut and macro which

1. takes selected line from editor to clipboard (Ctrl+X)
2. programmatically adjusts white space to indent second column
3. returns modified clipboard back to editor (Ctrl+V)